# Azure VPN client | How to enable login with MFA with each time connection is done

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-vpn, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to setUp Azure VPN for selected users, I have done all the steps as advised by MS:

1. P2S connection setup as Azure VPN
2. Give access to users for Azure VPN
3. Create a conditional access policy with MFA enabled for those users

Now I am able to Login with MFA for the first time, however once I disconnect and try reconnecting again the Azure VPN does not asks for any authentication (even for Username & Password), what I want to achieve here is to have MFA for each time the connection is done, is there anything I am missing while setting this up, any help would be hugely appreciated

BR
Sumil Jalota

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure out how to promt users for MFA on every sign in?